# using handlebars with precompiled templates not loading

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following code, but I still get the following error when templates.js loads:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

Here is how I'm loading the required scripts (first handlebars, then the precompiled tempaltes):

```
    var scripts = [
      '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.min.
js'
      , '/templates/templates.js'
    ];

    $.each(scripts, function(i, script){
      var el = document.createElement( 'script' );
      el.src = script;

      $body.append(el);
    });
```

But in the console I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so simple. Not all browser will load and use those js files in the same order that you specified ([Dynamic script loading](http://www.amirharel.com/2012/03/12/loading-scripts-sync-or-async/))

Think about using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: handlbebars won't work with requirejs out of the box. I don't want to use a patched version of handlebars either. I will probalby ditch Handlbars altother as its largely unusable in the real world.

Comment: @chovy You can just use a shim config option and export "Handlebars".